# Run laravel jobs one time at specific time only

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I came across a situation i want to trigger some code at specific time, i.e when user does booking, the freelancer must accept/reject the booking request, if he doesnt, after x duration (15* mins lets say) it would be rejected and user would get push notification. All code is done but currently im running a cronjob after each 1 minute which checks for any unresponded bookings and checks when their time (15mins, dynamic) passed so then I execute my code for afterward, it is not good i guess as its running db queuries over and over each minute.

I'm aware with laravel queue jobs as well but didnt see anything for me to run that job for a specific time only (i.e execute this job after 15mins, if it isnt responded, reject it)

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at Queue delay?

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#delayed-dispatching

This sounds like what you are looking for, I would just trigger the queue and delay when they make a booking so it executes 15 minutes after.

Comment: I've looked into it. There is a limit in delay, i.e 10min in future of delay as maximum and 15min for AWS SQS if we use that.

Comment: @KaleemQasim I couldn't find a delay limit on the docs, except for AWS SQS like you mentioned.  However if that does not work for you, my suggestion in this case is to use task scheduling: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#main-content You can probably mark the booking as a specific status and check it every minute for records older then x minutes then reject all records older than that.

Answer (score -1):

Use scheduled tasks.

```php
use App\Console\Commands\SendEmailsCommand;
 
$schedule->command('emails:send Taylor --force')->daily();
 
$schedule->command(SendEmailsCommand::class, ['Taylor', '--force'])->daily();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands